# SQL - How to avoid multiple OR operators in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
sqlite> .schema movie
CREATE TABLE movie (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, year INTEGER, nth TEXT, for_video BOOLEAN
  );
sqlite>
sqlite>
sqlite>
```

---

For the question:

Which movie(s), not counting movies whose titles start with punctuation, come first in alphabetical order, and which come last?

below syntax:

```sql
SELECT title 
FROM movie 
WHERE NOT(title LIKE '%!%' or title LIKE '%#%' or title LIKE '%$%')  
ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 1;
```

has never ending or operators.

---

Syntax should work in mysql and sqlite

How to avoid multiple `OR` operators that check for punctuations? yet to add more `OR` operators for punctuation check...

Comment: Divide `NOT(a OR b OR c)` to `NOT(a) AND NOT(b) AND NOT(c)`. If the conditions is one that you show strictly then try to use `NOT REGEXP`.

Comment: @Akina `Error: no such function: REGEXP` sqlite

Comment: If you use SQLite then remove excess [mysql] tag!

Comment: @Akina  I would like to know the syntax for both sqlite &  mysql, as mentioned inthe query

Answer (score 0):

For th first part (multiple ORs). Also note that the syntax is different for the join (`Like`)

You can create a table for punctuations and add the data into it

```
 Create table Punctuations (punckSign varchar(10))

 insert into Punctuations
 values ('!'), ('#'), ('$')
```

Then left join that with movie table as follows

**MySQL**

```
 SELECT title FROM movie m
 Left join Punctuations p 
 on  title  like concat('%',p.punckSign,'%')  
 where p.punckSign is null
```

**SQLite**

```
 SELECT title FROM movie m
 Left join Punctuations p 
 on  title  like '%'|| p.punckSign || '%'  
 where p.punckSign is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below using REGEXP

```
SELECT title 
FROM movie 
WHERE title not REGEXP '!|#|$'
ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `Error: no such function: REGEXP` in sqlite